# getting socket id of a client in flask socket.io

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

Is there a way to get socket id of current client? I have seen it is possible to get socket id in node.js. But it seems flask's socket.io extension is a little bit different than node's socketio.

Answer (score 15):

From [Flask-SocketIO documentation](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> The request object defines `request.namespace` as the name of the namespace being handled, and adds `request.sid`, defined as the unique session ID for the client connection

Answer (score 5):

Consider using `request.sid` which gets its value populated from the FlaskSocketIO library.

Answer (score 2):

I found it is possible in flask too.

In the flask's `request` object there is a socket object which has an id.

```
from flask import request
# ....
@socketio.on('connect')
def onConnect():
    currentSocketId = request.namespace.socket.sessid
# ....
```

Comment: Not recommended, this is an internal data structure that may change in the future. A better alternative is to create your own identifiers based on user information you have in the `session`, for example.